# Including an interactive document in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I know how to make an interactive document in rmarkdown by following this [page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-start.html). However, what I want is different. I want to create an interactive document, such as the example here:

````
---
title: "Shiny Document"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 30, min = 1, max = 50)

renderPlot({
  x    = faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
  bins = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

  # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
  hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})
```
````

And I want to include this in my Shiny app. I know that I can directly create a page (or tab) like this in the `ui` function in Shiny. However, I want to have a separate file storing the information of the page, instead of including everything in the `ui` function. Is that possible?